# TypeError: Failed to Fetch When Uploading Image Using S3 Presigned URL

Tags: image, amazon-s3, fetch, typeerror, pre-signed-url

We are seeing TypeError: Failed to Fetch errors when uploading an image using an S3 presigned URL.  This does not happen every time.

Here is the code to upload:

```
export const uploadToSecureURL = async (blob: Blob, fetchUrl: string) => {
  const file = new File([blob], 'blob.png', { type: 'image/png' });

  if (!fetchUrl || !fetchUrl.includes('https://')) {
    throw new Error('Incorrect fetchUrl given');
  }

  const res = await fetch(fetchUrl, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: file,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': file.type },
  });
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(
      `Uploading screenshot resulted in unexpected server response: ${res.statusText} (${res.status})`
    );
  }
  return res;
};
```

Here is the code to generate the presigned URLs:

```
import {
  CopyObjectCommand,
  DeleteObjectCommand,
  DeleteObjectsCommand,
  GetObjectCommand,
  HeadObjectCommand,
  ListObjectsV2Command,
  ListObjectsV2CommandInput,
  NoSuchKey,
  ObjectIdentifier,
  PutObjectCommand,
  S3Client,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';
import { ErrorCode, LogLevel, TangoError, toTangoError } from '../logging';
import { FileService } from './file-service';
import { File, FileBody } from './types';
import mime = require('mime');

async getUpdateFilePresignedURL(
    key: string,
    options?: {
      expiresInSeconds?: number;
      metadata?: { [key: string]: string };
      useAccelerateEndpoint?: boolean;
    }
  ): Promise<string> {
    this.maybeEnableTransferAcceleration(options?.useAccelerateEndpoint ?? false);
    const contentType = mime.getType(key);

    if (!contentType) throw new TangoError({ message: 'Invalid file type', code: ErrorCode.BAD_USER_INPUT });

    const command = new PutObjectCommand({
      Bucket: this.bucket,
      Key: key,
      Metadata: options?.metadata,
      ContentType: contentType,
    });

    return await getSignedUrl(this.s3client, command, {
      expiresIn: options?.expiresInSeconds ?? DEFAULT_EXPIRATION_TIME_IN_SECONDS,
    });
  }
```

We are not expecting to see TypeError: Failed to Fetch when trying to upload the image.  Is there a possibility that the url generated by S3 is invalid?